# Replace appended content on button click

Tags: jquery, replace

```
 $("#append"+i).html('<div id="entry'+i+'" class="entry'+i+'"></div>');
```

The above is done on button clicked I want to remove the entry+i and put the entry+i+1 in there.This is in a callback function inside so I can call the button like this.

```
$(document).on('click',"#id"+(i+1),function(){
      $("#entry"+i).remove();
    })
```

the problem is that i have en extra div each time I click another button how can I fix this?I want to replace my entry+i with my entry+i+1 and remove the previous one.
The added code.

```
 function createCallback( i ){
     return function(e){
         e.preventDefault();
         $("#append"+i).html('<div id="entry'+i+'" class="entry'+i+'">'+ '</div>');
         $(document).on('click',"#id"+(i+1),function(){
             $("#entry"+i).remove();
         })
         $(document).on('click',"#id"+(i-1),function(){
             $("#entry"+i).remove();
         })

      }
 }

 for(var i=0;i<10;i++){
    $('#id' + i).click( createCallback( i ) );
 }
```

Comment: Your code isn't good enough. Please show us your full necessary codes

Comment: There is a [replaceWith](http://api.jquery.com/replacewith/) in jquery but if you are just changing the contents of the same element like a `div` you can just change the inner html or txt of that `div` and it may be lighter on the browser.

Answer (score 0):

your code is not enough to provide exact solution. But conceptually check followings :

- wait before you remove, because of callback may be you are too fast to remove something which it not there yet.

.

```
$.when($.ajax("yourcallbackUrl")).then(function(data){
    $("#entry"+i).remove();
});
```

- Check the index : i (if it is correct)

Comment: the code works but it doesn;t work if you click the third button from the list etc if you skip the i doesn;t do it correctly i want it to remove the previous one and append a new one.